# MaxAuthenticationAge in WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-saml

What is the use of WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.setMaxAuthenticationAge in spring security. Do I need to set its value explicitly? 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/saml/websso/WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.html

Answer (score 5):

Quote from https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-advanced.html#time-interval (with added formatting)

> System allows users to single sign-on for up to `7200` seconds since their initial authentication with the IDP (based on value `AuthInstance` of the Authentication statement). Some IDPs allow users to stay authenticated for longer periods than this and you might need to change the default value by setting `maxAuthenticationAge` of the `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl` bean.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.

Comment: This is bonkers, and by that I mean the design of spring-security-saml. There is a perfect mechanism for this in `sessionNotOnOrAfter`. If the SP does not trust an authentication that was made more 7200 seconds ago, and asks the IdP for a new one, and gets *another* "old" assertion, you'll end up with a 403. This is badly broken behaviour by spring-security-saml. It should be fixed.

Comment: It seems that this is a global configuration. Would it be possible to configure it based on the idP?

Comment: @duncanportelli no, you'd have to extend spring-saml-security (WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl) and implement it